# Unable to run cloud code function of my parse server with cron linux

Tags: javascript, linux, cron, parse-server

I'm trying to do some scheduling functions on my parse-server. The server is hosted in AWS with a linux machine.

I followed the parse instruction using this code in my crontab:

```
* * * * *  curl -X POST -H 'X-Parse-Application-Id: appId' -H 'X-Parse-Master-Key: masterKey' https://my-parse-server.com/1/jobs/myJob
```

Of course I have changed to my masterKey, appId and server https.

My cloud code function:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("myJob", function(request, status) {
  console.log("teste");
  status.success()
});
```

So, I was waiting to my server log print (teste) every minute.

It didn't happen.

The only thing that the server logs every minute is:

> ParseServer-0 POST /parse/cloud/myJob - - ms - -

And if a try to run it directly in my server terminal:

```
ubuntu@ip-xxx-xx-x-xxx:~$ curl -X POST -H 'X-Parse-Application-Id: xxxx' -H 'X-Parse-Master-Key: xxxx' https://xxxx
<html>
<head><title>504 Gateway Time-out</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>504 Gateway Time-out</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.11.2</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I also tried to change the cloud function to :

```
Parse.Cloud.run("myJob", function(request, status) {
  console.log("teste");
  status.success()
});

Parse.Cloud.httpRequest("myJob", function(request, status) {
  console.log("teste");
  status.success()
});
```

Comment: You probably need to specify the full path of `curl` in crontab. Probably `/usr/bin/curl` (you can get it typing `which curl`).

Comment: Thank you, but still not working :(

Comment: You may check the section [Debugging crontab](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info). It contains different possible situations that may be the ones you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

Jobs are not part of any release yet, it's just been merged to the master branch a few days ago

https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/pull/2560

Stay tuned and keep you eyes on the release notes/changelog.

As you're using a function now, you should probably use: https://my-parse-server.com/parse/functions/myJob

Note that you should check properly the mount path and and the full URL. (I replaced /1 by /parse as it's the default.